# Git pull on remote repo 

Tags: git, pull

1. I have cloned a git repository(which is in our local server) in my machine.
2. I want to sync the latest changes from remote repository into our local server first and then on to my machine; Because server repository will be used by other colleagues as well.

   1. I can either directly log-in to the server and do git pull there, but it is restricted as the command level access to the server is restricted now.
   2. Can I do the step 1 activity from my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pull from the server if your don't log into it. However you can pull from your local repo, and push back to the server.

Comment: I think this the better option for now. I did a pull in my local repo got successful as well git pull <Repo> <Refs> ; but the tags of the remote repo are not still visible to me in my local branch; I want to create a stable branch based on a particular tag. I have checked git show-ref for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it from your machine if you can have access to a Windows/Samba share on this local server from your own machine. You would be able to run git inside that share from your machine without a hassle, except if you don't have a direct access to the remote repository from your machine.

Or you could do like CharlesB said, which is more "gitty". Fetch the remote from your local machine, then push to the local server. For the other co-worker, they won't see any differences.